# MongoDB query on same collection with count

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have only one collection "details". It is used in the query twice with different alias. As Mongo does not have alias, I think so mapreduce will give the results.
I also tried aggregation with unwind, but it will unwind on a field and not on the collection.
Any help with aggregation or mapreduce.

```
Collection:

"details"
    {
        "user_id":1,
        "lft":2
        "rgt":5
    },
    {
        "user_id":2,
        "lft":1
        "rgt":6
    },
    {
        "user_id":3,
        "lft":3
        "rgt":4
    }
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT CONCAT( REPEAT('-', COUNT(parent.user_id) - 1), node.user_id) 
    AS user_id
FROM details AS node,
    details AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.user_id
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

It should output:

```
  1
  -2
  --3
```

I have tried:

```
    $mongodb = Connections::get('default')->connection;
    $details = Details::connection()->connection->command(array(
        'aggregate' => 'details',
        'pipeline' => array( 
            array('$project' => array( 
                    '_id' => array(
                        'parent'=>array(
                            'puser_id'=>'$user_id',
                            'pleft'=>'$left',
                            'pright'=>'$right',                     
                            ),
                        'node'=>array(
                            'nuser_id'=>'$user_id',
                            'nleft'=>'$left',
                            'nright'=>'$right',
                            )
                        ),

                    ),
                    '$group'=>array('_id'=>'$_id.parent.puser_id'),
                    '$match' => array(
                        '$_id.node.nleft'=>array('$gt'=>'$_id.parent.pleft'),
                        '$_id.node.nright'=>array('$gt'=>'$_id.parent.pright')
                            )
            ),
        )
    ));
```

I am stuck at $group and $match!

Comment: Why don't you use the aggregation framework?

Comment: what's your business objective?  Might be a simpler way with Mongo

Comment: I have created a parent child collection in a single table using reference "The Nested Set Model" in: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/  I am implementing "Finding the Depth of the Nodes" from that article. The collection creation works ok!

Comment: Have you got any further with this Nilam?

Comment: Hi Ross, I compromised with one query which will give parent details and the looping all parents to find their child nodes giving a count. It will work for a few hundred thousand records. But over it the server will be too slow.

Comment: I don't think you can do this kind of recursive query with MongoDB (or any DB, really). Map/reduce may be a better bet, but will likely be very slow. You can walk up the parent chain and emit() for each step, but this will generate unnecessary duplicates exploding your intermediate result set, unless you are doing this for the trivial case of starting from a single node and tracing a single graph.
I also noticed if you're moving left, you have a circular path between 1 and 2 above.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by changing the schema:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5114a7eb9d5d0c640900001e"),
"user_id": "5114a7eb9d5d0c640900001d",
"username": "user8",
"refer_username": "user7",
"refer_id": "5114a7c59d5d0c6409000018",
    "ancestors": {
    "0": null,
     "1": "Initial",
     "2": "user6",
     "3": "user7"
    },
}
```

This has helped me to find all ancestors by using the query:

```
 user_id = '5114a7eb9d5d0c640900001d'
 db.details.find({'user_id':user_id});
```

and all descendents by using the query:

```
 username = 'user8'
 db.details.find('ancestors':username)
```

Without using Map/Reduce, and using aggregation framework, with $unwind function I am able to count all the ancestors and descendents of the user.

You can check this page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/ it will really improve your understanding of Model Tree structure for MongoDB. It is fast and better than MySQL.